# Core data context change causes crash

Tags: ios, core-data, crash

I have some Peoples profile, which I am saving in Core data. I receive them from server.

Next time when I run app, old data exists there, and I call a service call, which get more profiles including this.

I remove all the profiles and insert new.

When I try to work on existing screen, it crashes. I am pretty sure, that I changed database, and that object no more exists. While in reality, that object is inside CoreData but with another context.

Now, how can I improve this situation, that if I remove all Data and insert same data again, it shouldn't crash with existing data.

Let me know if anything wrong in Question, or I need to explain more.

Thanks.

Comment: show your crash

Comment: its profile_id is nil, simple, goes off its context, I am sure, I need best architect to improve this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If problem is really in "While in reality, that object is inside CoreData but with another context.", you can call the same object from needed context with it's NSManagedObjectID.

So just save your ids and pass them around, and when you need exact objects, call them from needed context with these ids

Comment: you mean that If I use NSManagedObjectID, it will go with new object?

Comment: I have heard of background update keeping context same, any thoughts on it?